# Two databases in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, merge, aspnetdb

I have two databases in my project.
One of them is the ASPNETDB.mdf.
I'm wondering if there is a solution to merge these two or link them.
Because I need my UserID from the ASPNETDB if I want to make a post to my other DB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you're installing aspnetdb you can choose exist DB where can be installed and appended aspnetdb. After you can use one db in your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can link one oledb database into a mssqlserver allowing cross database joins:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.InfoFromOtherDatabase 
   from dbo.myTable a inner join OtherServer.dbo.OtherTable b on a.id=b.id
```

See [here (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)  for details.